# Tool to list USB devices as tree in shell?

Tags: usb, lsusb, usbview

Is there any tool which lists the controller, hubs and devices of USB subsystem in their tree structure at the shell?

`lsusb` lists flatly and does not show all the details. `usbview` has a GUI, but shows the tree structure and all details of the devices. Any tool that shows whatever `usbview` does, but at the shell?

Comment: Have you tried the verbose option `lsusb -v` for details ?

Comment: @heemayl: Does not display as a tree.

Comment: yeah..now you need something that can sort that out..

Answer (score 25):

`-t` shows tree output:

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/1p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/2p, 5000M
```

This also shows the current speed, so you can see e. g. keyboard and mouse with 12 Mbps.

Use `-tv` for more verbose output, including class descriptors (vendor):

```
$ lsusb -tv
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 5000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/1p, 5000M
        ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. 
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/2p, 5000M
            ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. 
...
```

The verbose flag can be repeated for even more detailed output:

```
$ lsusb -tvv
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 5000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2  /dev/bus/usb/002/001
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/1p, 5000M
        ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. 
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2  /dev/bus/usb/002/002
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/2p, 5000M
            ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. 
            /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-2.1  /dev/bus/usb/002/004
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        ID 0451:8140 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-5  /dev/bus/usb/002/003
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
            ID 0451:8140 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
            /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-5.3  /dev/bus/usb/002/00/
```

Comment: `lsusb -t` loses the human readable device descriptors that `lsusb` shows. Add `-v` to get them back, or `lsusb -tv`